# Find the determinant of the matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

If
$\text{det}\left[\begin{matrix}a & 1 & c\\
b & 1 & d\\
e& 1 & f
\end{matrix}\right]= -3$ 
and $\text{det}\left[\begin{matrix}a & 1 & c\\
b & 2 & d\\
e& 3 & f
\end{matrix}\right]= 5$ 
find
$\text{det}\left[\begin{matrix}a & -4 & c\\
b & -7 & d\\
e& -10 & f
\end{matrix}\right]$.

How do I approach this? The section deals with the effect of row operations on the determinate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The determinant is linear in every row and in every column. Thus, this problem is equivalent to finding $φ(-4,-7,-10)$ for a linear map $φ \colon ℚ^3 → ℚ$ with $φ(1,1,1) = -3$ and $φ(1,2,3)= 5$. Do you see that – what is $φ$ here? Can you solve this reduced problem?

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks. I just need to solve a system of equations.

Comment: @johnny133253 Yeah, or you just guess the linear combination $(-4,-7,-10) = μ(1,1,1) + λ(1,2,3)$.

Comment: Yup, so $\mu = -1$ and $\lambda = -3$. Much appreciated.

Comment: @johnny133253,so have you got the value of determinant asked?

Comment: Yes its $(-1)(-3) + (-3)(5) = -12$